# getSerializable returns different types depending on how app exited

Tags: java, android, arrays, types, casting

I need to save an `int[][]` into a `Bundle` so it could be saved during `onSaveInstanceState()` and restored on `onCreate()`. First, I've decided to make it straightforward and flatten a 2D array into 1D and deflatten on load. It all worked fine.

I've decided to find an easier way. I was told that 2D arrays are serializable, so I made it something like this:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("CELLS_STATE",universe.getUniverse());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}//onSaveInstanceState
```

where `universe.getUniverse()` returns an `int[][]`.

Reloading within `onCreate()`:

```
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {//save data exists, reload it
        universe = new Universe( (int[][])savedInstanceState.getSerializable("CELLS_STATE") );
    }
```

Here's the catch. If I run the program and turn my phone so the screen changes orientation, it loads perfectly fine.

**But**, when I press the home button and then kill the app using an app killer (in my case it is Battery Doctor) and try to start it again from the menu, it crashes and I can launch it only from the second attempt, and the saved state is lost. The error that is given on that crash points to the line with `getSerializable` I've specified above, and it is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to int[][]
```

This confuses me. So, whenever screen orientation changes (and maybe something else), `getSerializable` returns something that can be cast to a 2D array (probably, `Serializable`). But whenever the app is killed, it returns something that cannot be cast. What causes such a strange behaviour and is there a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What causes such a strange behavior...?

It appears that this is a bug in the `Parcel`'s implementation, I recommend to read comment [#6](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64583#c6) which contains the very good explanation of bug's nature.

> .. and is there a way to bypass it?

The following code should work:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    final Object[] objects = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("CELLS_STATE");
    final int[][] cells = new int[objects.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        cells[i] = (int[]) objects[i];
    }

    universe = new Universe(cells);
}
```

Comment: That explains a lot! Maybe I will try to store the whole instance of `Universe` class (instead of 2d array of primitives) then, and make it Serializable. If it doesn't work, I will stick to my initial solution with flattening.